# node:net - how can I retrieve port and host info from a client socket?

Tags: node.js

I have a TCP client.

```
import net from 'node:net'

const tcpClient = new net.Socket()

tcpClient.connect(req.body.port, req.body.host, function() {
  console.log(`nodejs net client for TCP connection succesfully connected to port ${req.body.port} and host ${req.body.host}`);
})
// output: succesfully connected to port 4001 and host 192.168.10.45
```

The client object contains data object, which holds info whether the socket is open or not (data._readableState.closed), but how can I figure out what host and port it is connected to? I can't find it anywhere.
I check the tcpClient like this:

```
tcpRouter.get('/checkTCPConnection', (req, res) => {
  res.send(tcpClient)
})
```

And there's no TCPClient.remoteAddress or anything like that

If I try:

```
tcpRouter.get('/checkTCPConnection', (req, res) => {
  res.send(tcpClient.remoteAddress)
})
```

I get timeout error in terminal (server) and invalid argument error in the browser.

Comment: **You** have to tell it where it should connect to. Why do you think it magical connects anywhere?! Also, are `socket.remoteAddress` and `socket.remotePort` what you are looking for? The node documentation is not perfect, but very well done, i suggest you read it: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/net.html#class-netsocket

Comment: First of all, of course I have a running connection, so I have connected somewhere, but I want to read this info programatically. Second, what you mention is probably what I am looking for but still I can't find it. It's only in documentation, but it doesn't work in practice.  That's why I ask. Maybe I'm doing smt wrong, maybe I don't understand smt. IDK.

Comment: .localAddress works (returns 0.0.0.0) but localPort, remoteAddress and remotePort don't.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me:

```js
const { Socket } = require("net");

const client = new Socket();

client.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("Connected to", client.remotePort, client.remoteAddress)
});

client.connect(80, "example.com");

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Info:", client.remotePort, client.remoteAddress)
}, 1000);
```

Output:

```
Connected to 80 93.184.216.34
Info: 80 93.184.216.34
```

Keep in mind, that this works asynchronous.
If you do:

```js
const { Socket } = require("net");

const client = new Socket();
client.connect(80, "example.com");

console.log("Info:", client.remotePort, client.remoteAddress);
```

you get:

```
Info: undefined undefined
```

`.localAddress` and `.localPort` are **your** machine network info.
`.remoteAddress` and `.remotePort` (as its name indicate) are the port/address of your peer/target.

From your question its not clear for me, if you want your machine network info, or the remote ones. If you want your information, just swap `.remote...` with `.local...`

Hope this help you.